# what is topN in nutch 1.3?

Tags: nutch, web-crawler, top-n

I read in sites that nutch fetch links from every link equls to topN.I have 4 links but when nutch crawl my links, all result that returned with nutch are equals topN. it means if i have 4 links and topN = 10, nutch fetch 10 links from all links not every link.end of crawl i have 10 links. help me.

Answer (score 2):

From another view **topN** means how many documents to get from each level of the **depth**.
**depth** means how many generate/fetch/update cycles to carry out to get full page coverage.